# What does か at the end of the headline signify?

Tags: grammar, sentence-final-particles

> **米追加関税第４弾　３８０５品目対象、スマホも　措置発動は６月下旬以降か**

I understand this as, "The USA has added additional tarrif/tax on 3805 articles/products (according to bullet point 4), which includes smartphones. To be put into practice from third half of June"

What role does か at the end play here? Wouldn't the headline be fine without it or is it some kind of transformation か like コンピューターか (computerization) ?

Article for reference: https://www.sankei.com/world/news/190514/wor1905140011-n1.html

Comment: 化 in the sense of *-ization* is always written in kanji in newspapers.