# Could anyone tell me about how to use か at the end of the news article I see it a lot and get confused about it all the time

Tags: grammar, meaning, words, usage, particles

[image]

I get confused about it all the time
Please explain how to use and how to translate it
Thank you for your explanation

Comment: The second part you took a picture of provides a hint: **タイ**・バンコクで**会談**を開く可能性がある

Comment: Related: [What is the meaning of “超か” in this news headline?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68210/5010) and [What does か at the end of the headline signify?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68210/5010)

Answer (score 5):

The sentence-ending か expresses ***indefiniteness***, ***incertitude***, etc.  It is pretty much synonymous to a question mark.

> 「日韓外相、タイで会談」 without the 「か」

means that it is **definite** that the Japanese and Korean foreign ministers will meet for talks in Thailand.

> 「日韓外相、タイで会談**か**」 with the 「か」

means that the meeting is **indefinite**.  It is not official yet even though it seems as though it might happen.

If you read the first sentence of the article, it actually says:

> 「会談を開く**可能性**がある」

= "there is a ***possibility*** that they might hold a meeting."  That is incertitude, isn't it?

The usage is quite simple and consistent.  I could not think of an exceptional usage of this 「か」.

As for translations, the principle stays the same.  Just make sure that they express indefiniteness, incertitude, etc.  One might use:

"Foreign Ministers of Japan and Korea to Meet in Thailand?" by using a question mark or

"Possible Talks in Thailand between Japan and Korea", etc.

Your English should be 100 times as good as mine.